# why I can't use the (? :) operators like if-else statements in Java?

Tags: java

I can define variables using the (? :) operators. But why I can't use it as an if-else statement to execute statements based on a condition?

I tried doing the following:

```
char first = queue.remove();
(first == 'W') ? women++ : men++;
```

But did not work.

Comment: Because you have to return something into a variable. That is not the same semantics as an if/else statement.

Comment: Of course you can: `women += (first == 'W') ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Have a look on Java ternary operator for your understanding https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: @alfasin I know that but I am asking why I can't use it to run statements.

Comment: "Why can't I fit the square block into the circular hole?" --- The ternary operator is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: The general syntax for ternary operator is "result = testCondition ? value1 : value2" that's why you can't perform your statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called the ternary operator, and it results in an expression, not a statement. Semi-colons follow statements.

The following is valid because it's both a statement and an expression (if the return type of `foo` is void, then it's only a statement):

```
foo();
```

And the following is invalid for the same reason your ternary operator example is invalid (a literal string is only an expression):

```
"xyzzy";
```

If you want to execute one statement or another depending on a boolean, use an if-then statement. If you want an expression to take one value or another depending on a boolean, use the ternary operator. They're not interchangeable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the differences between expressions and statements in this case (using an example maybe) Thanks

Comment: So expression can be only assigned to variables?

Comment: You can assign an expression to a variable or pass it as an argument to a function that you invoke.

Comment: I wanna check my understanding. == is an operator, it needs two expressions, right?

Answer (score 0):

While `if-statement`'s allow the logical flow of code, the *ternary operator* is actually an [operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) that takes three operands. The ternary operator results in an expression, not a statement.

Comment: The last part of this answer is the exact same as the previous answer. Did you just copy it?

Comment: Nope, he just beat me to it.